# Why using HTML for web pages

Tags: html

I know that my question maybe strange but until now I do not understand why using HTML for web pages ?  why do not we create web pages as normal text rather than using HTML and then write programs that parse it .

what is relationship between HTTP and HTML ?

can HTTP send data as files that is non HTML like txt and png ? if not , why ?

Answer (score 2):

We write the web pages as text, and then write the browsers; which parse the HTML/XML.

Answer (score 1):

> can HTTP send data as files that is non HTML like txt and png ?

Yes HTTP can.

> what is relationship between HTTP and HTML ?

HTTP is a protocol that describes how data is exchanged over the network.
HTML is a format of data, that explains how the page should be displayed (italic, bold, etc.)